# PATCHing user in batch operation with Mailchimp V3 API returns OK, but won't update changes

Tags: mailchimp

I guess what I'm asking here is: how to debug my request if both the batch and update member call to the API returns "OK" ?

Comment: For what it's worth, the same call, just not in a batch one, works perfectly fine.

Comment: You do know that the API v3 batch is asynchronous, right? You'll need to wait for the batch to complete as described [in the docs](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-batch-operations/).

Comment: Yep, I knew. And as it turns out, it was the API wrapper I used that caused problem.